# What is the special word for person who likes making fool of others?

Tags: word-choice

What is the special word for person who likes making fool of others?

馬鹿にすることが好きな人は特別の言葉で何と言われていますか。

For example, A is such a person. So we can call A as the word in question.

Answer (score 4):

「おちょくり屋{や}」 for one.  Light, conversational and very common as a word.

「いじラー」 for another.  Fairly slangy (and not so common).  Don't even know why I know this word at all.  The base verb is 「いじる」.　 I trust you have seen slangy words in the 「〇〇ラー」 form such as 「マヨラー」("mayonaise lover"), 「アムラー」 ("a huge Amuro Namie fan"), etc.

「毒舌家{どくぜつか}」(one with a bad mouth or a sharp tongue) might or might not be what you are looking for, but it is, if anything, a good word to add to anyone's vocabulary.